# flutter RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..4: 5 on CarouselSlider

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-slider

I want to show the all images from the API in the carousel and for items, I want to show 2 items per slide.
and it works correctly what I want. but in every last item, it shows me the error of `CarouselSlider`. I don't know why it gives me this error. I tried to solve it but failed because I don't know why they give me this error in the last item.

here is my code:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';

class PersonImages extends StatefulWidget {

 PersonImages({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_PersonImages createState() => _PersonImages();
}

class _PersonImages extends State<PersonImages>{

 var UsriD = Auth.prefs?.getString('usrid');
 var Imagedata;
 var img = "";
 var user = "";

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
 getImageData();
 }

 getImageData() async{
  var res = await http.get(Uri.https('www.*******.net', '/index.php',{'act':'usrPhotos','Usrid': '${UsriD}'}));
 Imagedata = jsonDecode(res.body);
 //print(Imagedata);
 setState(() {});
 print(res.body);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//print(Imagedata);

return
  Imagedata != null? CarouselSlider.builder(
      options: CarouselOptions(
        //height: 150,
        aspectRatio: 2.0,
        enableInfiniteScroll: false,
        //viewportFraction: 0.8,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        viewportFraction: 1,
      ),
      itemCount: (Imagedata.length / 2).round(),
      //itemCount: 3,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, int  pageViewIndex) {
        final int first = index * 2;
        final int second = first + 1;
        return
          Row(
            children: [first, second].map((idx) {
              return Expanded(
                //flex: 2,
                child:  Container(
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
                      child:
                      Image.network(
                        "https://www.*******.net/files/images/${Imagedata[idx]['image']}",
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        width: 200,
                        height: 200,
                      ),
                    ),

                ),
              )
              );
            }).toList(),
          );
      }
  ): const Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
  );
  }
  }
```

Here is my error and output :- [image: Error and output]

please help me if anyone knows how to resolve it.
is anyone knows how to do this so answer my question?

Comment: It would be better if you provide separate widget that will reproduce the same issue, because there are data we cant access. But seeing the it most likely coming form from `second` operation and the one used inside image

Comment: thank you for your reply. but i didn't get it.

Comment: check 5th item, it is getting null I belive

Comment: maybe you are right. but how i shoe the last one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of an odd number length, for example 5

you divided it by 2. which is 2.5 Rounded it then the value is 3.

Now when it loops for the third time. It will try and fetch 2*2 + 1. now you will try and find the element by id 5 which doesn't exist. You can try

```
 itemCount: (Imagedata.length / 2).floor(),
```

Note you may lose the last image in case of an odd length.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. it works now error does not show but  I lose the last image I also want to show the last image. how can i get it.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for taking 2 items at once? Why not directly use the length to generate images?

Comment: because i want to show 2 items per slide

Comment: So you can use viewport fraction set to 0.5 which will take 50% of the screen width

Comment: ok so if i use `viewport fraction: 0.5` then no need to set `Imagedata.length / 2`  right?

Comment: Yeah absolutely

Answer (score 0):

Try checking null like

```dart
Imagedata[idx]['image']!= null?
 Image.network("...${Imagedata[idx]['image']}", ) 
       :Text("cant find image index"),
```